# Elementor Form : "An error occurred" when i use a custom webhook url

Tags: wordpress, forms, webhooks, elementor

I get a message `An error occurred.` from elementor form when i submit my elementor form.
I configured the Actions after submit with a webhook to a custom url.
I don't know if the problem is my hook function not responding as it should.

[Configuration : After Form Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px6LU.png)

[Configuration : WebHook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI7ak.png)

[The error message after the submition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz8C3.png)

I should point out that when I remove the webhook from the Actions after submit list, I no longer get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem

My custom url was not responding correctly, I added `return json_encode(array("success"=>true));` to the end of the callback function and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I also got an Elementor Forms error message, which turned out to be a timeout issue.

By default, the timeout is set to only 5 seconds. This can be increased by using an add_filter in PHP. For example, if you are using make.com as the webhook, you can specify:

```
add_filter('http_request_timeout', function($timeout, $url = '') {
    $start_with = 'https://hook.us1.make.com';
    
    //return is_string($url) && str_starts_with($url, $start_with) // PHP 8
    return is_string($url) && strncmp($url, $start_with, strlen($start_with)) === 0 // PHP 7 or older
        ? 30 // TODO: set appropriate timeout, WordPress default is 5 seconds
        : $timeout; // return unchanged url for other requests
}, 10, 2);
```

See the original issue here:
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/20452

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was in SSL certificate status.
I tried request from postman and receive an warning, that de SSL Certificate is unabled to verify. "Unable to verify the first certificate"

Change to another domain with SSL correctly verified and works.